# Not able to change the button color onclick jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on mvc5 in view i have created the below input

```
<input onclick="buttonclick(this)" id="btnspanish" type="button" value="Spanish">
```

JavaScript:

```
function buttonclick(obj) {
    $(this).addClass("background");
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: could you provide what you are getting as "this".?

Comment: Your example is confused, could you provide the html and javascript code?
And if you want to change the color, you must use .css("color","red") for example, or you have a css class named "background"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code cannot work. `this` in the scope of function will not be the instance of the button. You are passing in button instance via function parameter as `obj`, so that's what you need to use in a jQuery selector:

```
function buttonclick(obj) {
    $(obj).addClass("background");
}
```

Comment: @Boopathi. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. [Also look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)